# Material UI/React Custom theme dark mode is giving me two very slightly different shades of grey

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Ok so I'm working on my own reddit clone with a custom Material UI theme, and I've run into this significant issue that I can't seem to fix.

[The left and the right containers are different shades of grey.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAdn5.png)

On the left the hierarchy of components is:

```
<main>
  <Container>
    <Grid>
      <Grid>
        <Grid>
          <Card>
            <Grid>
              <CardContent>
              <Grid>
              <Grid>
              <Grid>
```

On the right the hierarchy of components is:

```
<main>
  <Container>
    <Grid>
      <Grid>
        <div>
          <Card>
            <div>
              <CardContent>
              <Divider>
```

I have a custom theme that changes `theme.palette.background.paper` and `theme.palette.background.default`

`default` is a dark slate and `paper` is a pure white with opacity 0.04

I also put `shadows: Array(25).fill('none')`

as well as setting `theme.palette.grey`[50-900] to shades of my background dark slate
also I do have `theme.palette.type = dark`

I've been playing around with it for hours and I can't figure out why they're slightly different.

Its definitely not my eyes cause I checked the actual hexes.

Any help is greatly appreciated! I can answer any further questions if you have them.

Thanks!

The repo is [github.com/sloont/sloont-mui-react](https://github.com/sloont/sloont-mui-react)

Comment: Something tells me it's because you are using alpha channel (opacity). Anyhow, you'd be better off if you showed a working sample of your code so we can test ourselves.

Comment: That's my working theory. Setting Paper background to an rgba will end up stacking them, but I'm not about it. It seems like there's a different grey coming from content on the right. One that isn't controlled by the Paper background

Comment: If anything, use theme overrides to get a consistent look. Are you familiar with using a ThemeProvider?

Comment: @JoelHager I am using a theme provider. This is how I override the presets.

Comment: Are you targetting the 'different-looking' one to make it match the other? You should be able to do that using a theme override on the component that looks inconsistent.

Comment: @JoelHager Yes. I manually changed the background color on all of the components involved. Its always a little bit off. Each paper styles the div with the provided transparency, but I think one of the elements that isn't paper is providing a different gray background.

Comment: You should be able to tell which one is doing that by using Chrome Developer Tools

Comment: @JoelHager Yeah I wen't through dev tools on all of them when I tried to change the background of each component. They all say they have a background: #121212 which would be the background color of the theme palette.

Comment: Yes, but there *may* be another `<div>` or other element between z-indices that has an `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)` for instance. Is it a public page that you can link to so I can take a look?

Comment: Here is the repo hosted on netlify https://sad-ritchie-9d5f31.netlify.app/ data is straight from reddit.com.json so it will likely give you a CORS error in your browser that you have to disable to fetch the content.

Click projects --> snips button

Comment: @JoelHager, I think I know what is causing it. Only the background is opaque, so could box shadows rendering behind the element be it?

Comment: That was not it.

Comment: Which parts are you saying should be the same?

Comment: The post containers and the container with the subreddit list